# extract php data from json

Tags: php, json

I am trying to extract some data from a json and i'm stuck. here the start of the json:

```
    {torrent: "",rss: {channel: {title: "The Pirate Bay - TV shows",link: "test"}}}
```

and here my code:

```
    <?php
    require_once 'rss_php.php';    
    $rss = new rss_php;
    $rss->load('http://rss.thepiratebay.se/205');
    $jsonData = json_encode($rss->getRSS());
    $phpArray = json_decode($jsonData);
    foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) { 
        echo "<p>$key | $value</p>";
    }
    ?>
```

All it returns is

```
 Torrent|
```

How to bypass the torrent: "".

Comment: What is `rss_php.php`?

Comment: `$some_var = json_decode(json_encode($some_other_var));`? Hmmmmmm....

Comment: What exactly does `$rss->getRSS()` return?

Comment: It's a script that i have downloaded on the net to change a rss feed to json format. if i echo the jsonData i got the json file.

Comment: try following the another stackoverflow post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145464/json-parsing-with-php-foreach

Comment: yes normally i dont have problem to export data like the one in the post but it seems like the torrent:"" block the rest of the json, if i use foreach ($phpArray->{rss} as $key) it's blank

Answer (score 0):

I assume rss_php is this thing:
http://rssphp.net/download/

Try this:

```
<?php
require_once 'rss_php.php';
$rss = new rss_php;
$rss->load('http://rss.thepiratebay.se/205');
print_r($rss->getRSS());
?>
```

Check the source of the webpage. That is the data in your array. You can directly use it without the use of json. Because there are arrays in arrays, you cannot easely foreach through the results. Do something like:

```
$arr = $rss->getRSS();
echo $arr['rss']['channel']['title'];
```

Edit:
If you want to foreach through all the results, I suggest something like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'rss_php.php';
$rss = new rss_php;
$rss->load('http://rss.thepiratebay.se/205');
$arr = $rss->getRSS();
//foreach over all the stuff in the channel
foreach ($arr['rss']['channel'] as $key=>$val)
{
  //In the array are keys like "title" and "comments", but we only want to iterate over the "item:1" (or some other number than 1), so only echo if the first 4 letters of the key are "item"
  if (substr($key,0,4) == "item")
  {
    //echo the title, but you can also echo other things in that array. Check the code with the print_r to easily see what's in the feed
    echo $val['title'].'<br />';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: You're right on, thanks so much for your time and patience this will help me a lot. thanks again